# Two models depends on each other – catch 22

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my scenario:

A model called Course has many CourseCodes. A CourseCode belongs to a Course.
A CourseCode can't be created without Course and a Course can't be created without at least one CourseCode.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_codes
  validate :existence_of_code
private
  def existence_of_code
    unless course_codes.any?
      errors[:course_codes] << "missing course code"
    end
  end
end

class CourseCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  validates_presence_of :course
end
```

The whole scenario feels a bit like catch 22.
Is there a way to create both on the same time?
I'm using Rails 3.2

Comment: Why does a CourseCode *have* to have a course attached to it? Would it not be ok for a CourseCode to be created as a placeholder for courses to be added later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by using [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent. By default nested.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_codes, inverse_of: :course
  validate :existence_of_code

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_codes

private
  def existence_of_code
    unless course_codes.any?
      errors[:course_codes] << "missing course code"
    end
  end
end

class CourseCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course, inverse_of: :course_codes
  validates_presence_of :course
end
```

Used like this.

```
Course.create!({
  course_codes_attributes: [{ code: "TDA123" }],
  # ...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks good to me. Removing the `validates_presence_of :course` might make things easier on you, too, as it will tend to get in the way an not add much.

When you create a course, do it like this:

```
Course.create course_codes: [CourseCode.new(...), CourseCode.new(...)]
```

ActiveRecord will figure things out.

Comment: See my comment on @Andrew's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could add an `unless` to whichever model you would plan to create first. For instance:

```
class CourseCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  validates_presence_of :course, :unless => lambda { Course.all.empty? }
end
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want any `CourseCodes` without an actually `Course`.

Comment: Is CourseCode just an attribute of Course then? Why not make CourseCode a string or integer on the Course model?

Comment: As you have described it your situation is theoretically impossible, not just in programming but in reality. You have to pick one to create first, then create the second associated thing. Even if you just did this on pen and paper there would be a split second delay between when you made the first and second thing.

Comment: @Oleander - Andrew is right, but it's not so easy in ActiveRecord to make course codes into an array of strings or integers on a model. You should consider just not creating a CourseCode without having an associated Course model.

Comment: @Andrew A course can have one or more codes, that is why I have not added a code attribute to the course model.